# Entity Framework and reactive

Tags: entity-system

In my games using entity framework (for example using https://github.com/libgdx/ashley ) help me to separate data from logic in different systems.
But a problem I've found is how to handle events between systems using messages. A possible solution of this could be reactive programming ( like https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava ), so for example an observer can be notified of changes on a specific model and react on that.

I'm not sure if this breaks the data / logic separation, because it will be at system level, any thoughts on that ?

Not sure also how to approach the ui part using also events from rxjava

Comment: _"But a problem I've found is how to handle events between systems using messages."_ What kind of "events"? Is there any harm in having those systems know about each other and communicate directly?

Comment: one of my goals is to create indipendent systems, so my idea is to create a message bus between systems to separate them and react on events

Comment: Why do you want to create independent systems?

Comment: more easy to manage, change, evolve

Answer (score 1):

I did not look in depth the framework you're proposing, so my answer is based on "using the observer pattern to help de-couple systems to make them independent, easier to manage, change, evolve".

This post is not a definitive answer, it's just a point of view.

Using the observer pattern, with messages, is *a* way to solve communication situations between systems. However, I'm not sure it is "easier to manage, change, evolve": you'll still need to determine what kind of messages are to be transmitted and received, you'll still need to setup the listening end. Although, strictly speaking, your system will be independent, a system is rarely evolving in its own silo, it's always part of the rest of your software.

From experience, using events to de-couple systems may make the software harder to read, with the execution flow more difficult to follow.

Depending on your events and messages passed around, it *could* make your program a bit faster.

Alternatively, you could define your contracts between your systems using Interfaces, which are implemented by the interested system, then injected into the other systems. Those systems then take for granted that the host system may or may not be there. Something like this (pseudocode):

```
interface IFrameTimeProvider
    double getFrameTime();

class SimulationSystem : IFrameTimeProvider
    double getFrameTime() { return frameTime_; }
    
class UiSystem
    construct( IFrameTimeProvider frameTimeProvider )
    {
        frameTimeProvider_ = frameTimeProvider;
    }
    
    void draw()
    {
        if ( frameTimeProvider_ )
            renderer.drawText( "frameTime = " + frameTimeProvider_.getFrameTime() );
    }
    
    IFrameTimeProvider frameTimeProvider_;
```

This also comes with its load of boilerplate handling.